# How to detect multiple strings in $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?

Tags: php, superglobals

I would like to detect an array of strings in `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` to define a constant for environment like dev/prod.
Basically, if `localhost` or `.dev` is in the URL, that would set the constant to "prod".

Here is my try but I always got `"prod"` even if my current url is "localhost:3000" or "site.dev":

```
// Define environment
$dev_urls = array(".dev", "localhost");
if (str_ireplace($dev_urls, "", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) == $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]){
    define("ENV", "dev");
} else {
    define("ENV", "prod");
}
```

---

Finally used this code which works like a charm

```
// Define environment
$dev_urls = array(".dev", "localhost", "beta.");
if (str_ireplace($dev_urls, "", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) != $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]){
    define("ENV", "dev");
} else {
    define("ENV", "prod");
}
```

Comment: I never received any feedback regarding the answer I left; did it solve your problem? If it did, marking it as accepted would be appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `SERVER_NAME` is defined in the server config, it never changes no matter what URL you use to reach that page.

I believe you want to use `HTTP_HOST` instead.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost' || substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], -4) == '.dev')
    define('ENV', 'dev');
else
    define('ENV', 'prod');
```

Comment: Agree, but it doesn't seems to solve the issue, always got "prod".

Comment: @flks Because your hacky `if` statement doesn't make sense. Just check `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost')` to determine if you are in dev enviroment.

Comment: The fact is I can access the dev URL as localhost:3000 **or** site.dev

Comment: Yep it works! But the challenge was to use an array to read and change it easily. The question is more how can I detect an array of strings in this `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`?

Comment: `(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ['localhost', '.dev']) !== false)` is true if any of those words exist on the string.

Comment: But it doesn't seem a fit way of testing it because both `www.localhost.net` and `www.deviantart.net` for instance will match your criteria, and thats not what you are looking for.